# Prove that $\text{Dom } (S\circ R) ⊆ \text{Dom }R $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let $R$ be a relation from $A$ to $B$ and $S$ be a relation from $B$ to $C$.

Suppose, $x \in \text{Dom }(S\circ R)$. Then, it follows that there $\exists y \in C$ such that $(x,y) \in S\circ R $. Since $S\circ R$ is a subset of $A\times C$ and by the definition of $\text{Dom }(S\circ R)$.

Thus there $\exists y \in C$ such that $(\exists r \in B)[(x,r)\in R$ and $(r,y)\in S ]$.

Therefore, it follows that $x\in \text{Dom }R$, since the statement $(\exists r \in B)(x,r)\in R$ satisfies the requirement for membership in $\text{Dom }R$.

Is this proof correct? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct.

Alternative:

If $a\notin\text{Dom }R$ then no $b\in B$ exists with $aRb$.

Consequently no $b\in B$ and $c\in C$ exist with $aRb\wedge bSc$.

This allows the conclusion that $a\notin\text{Dom }(S\circ R)$.

Comment: You have used contrapositive here. isn't it?

Comment: Can you please tell me about how to negate this statement from pure logic $ a \in Dom(R)$. It is a bi conditional statement. So negation of biconditional statemtn would yield ( not p and q) or (p and not q). Which one to pick?

Comment: If $p$ denotes the proposition that $a\in\text{Dom}(S\circ R)$ and $q$ denotes the proposition that $a\in\text{Dom}(R)$ then it must be shown that $p\implies q$. In my answer it is shown that $\neg q\implies \neg p$. Both statements are equivalent with $\neg p\vee q$ so have the same meaning.

Comment: Yes i have understood that. But please answer my other query

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but will give it a try. We can prove $p\implies q$ by proving that $\neg\neg (p\implies q)$, i.e. $\neg(p\wedge\neg q)$ i.e. $\neg\neg q\vee \neg p$ i.e. $\neg q\implies\neg p$. Is that what you are aiming at?

Comment: How to negate that proposition $a \in Dom(R)$.

Comment: Because negating above means negating biconditional statement which on then gives two statements

Comment: Just $a\notin\text{Dom}(R)$ or $\neg a\in\text{Dom}(R)$. That's all I can find. I have a blind spot for your difficulty. What is a "biconditional" statement then? I would expect $2$ conditions. What are these conditions?